# echo vs output variable

Tags: php, optimization

Someone once told me, that it is good for performance, not to open and close php tags and use echo all the time, like that:

```
<hgroup>
    <h1><?php echo getHeading1(); ?></h1>
    <h2><?php echo getHeading2(); ?></h2>
</hgroup>
```

Instead he uses an output variable and echoes it in the end.

```
$output .= '<hgroup>
    <h1>' . getHeading1(); . '</h1>
    <h2>' . getHeading2(); . '</h2>
</hgroup>';

echo $output;
```

Does that really make any difference? When do I use which method?

Comment: This is not WordPress related, so off topic here. However, does not exists any performance difference in the 2 methods, it's a matter of personal preferences.

Comment: As said this is not WP-related. The time that it has to be rendered should still be the same cause the two functions are executed in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this topic was [addressed quite thoroughly here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2437413/1542064). I might add that within the WordPress community it is common syntax practice to default to echoing tags with an option or alternative/interior function to return the result instead. This I believe is driven by the level of code experience the average user within WordPress has and understanding a simple tag structure is "easier" than string concatenation of a php variable. The goal of extensibiltiy also drives this mentality by providing modular that can be "dropped" into a template in a similar vien of `add_action`.